# Is a shell provided by `ssh username@server` login, and does it execute ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, ssh, configuration, login, profile

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

> **Invoked by remote shell daemon**
>
> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard
>   input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the
>   remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd. If
>   Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes
>   commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists and is readable. It
>   will not do this if invoked as sh. The `--norc` option may be used to
>   inhibit this behavior, and the `--rcfile` option may be used to force
>   another file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd generally invoke
>   the shell with those options or allow them to be specified.

Is a shell provided by `ssh username@server` login or nonlogin?

If  it is a login shell, why doesn't it executes commands from `~/.profile`, but from `~/.bashrc` according to the bash manual?

Thanks.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, but the bash manual isn't OS specific.

Comment: Specs of the system you are logging in to?

Comment: specs of the remote OS, not yours.

Comment: can be Ubuntu, or any other Linux. The bash manual is not server-specific either.

Comment: Put `alias hewoo='echo "bashrc got invoked"'` in `~/.bashrc` on the remote system, then `ssh` to it and do `hewoo`. That should clarify it for you. :3

Comment: What is your login shell on the remote system? `ssh myuser@host 'getent passwd myuser'`

Comment: @glennjackman I don't have a remote system to try. I used to.

Comment: So this is a theoretical question then.

Comment: I doubt that this is qualified as theoretical.

Comment: It is from your perspective. Also, you do have a remote system, your own — install the SSH server and `ssh you@localhost`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH starts a login shell, as alluded to in [its manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> If a *command* is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

You can verify this within Bash with

```
shopt login_shell
```

which will show whether it is running as a login shell.

Bash’s behaviour when started remotely, whether as a login shell or otherwise, is as documented in the section you quote. The behaviour you’re comparing it with is that of [interactive shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f.html), and a remote shell adds the `.bashrc` processing on top of the interactive login shell behaviour.

Note that Ubuntu systems typically have a `.bash_profile` script, which takes priority over `.profile`, and they typically have `.bash_profile` source `.bashrc` in any case...

Comment: "Bash’s behaviour when started remotely, whether as a login shell or otherwise, " Does it matter that the remoate bash shell is interactive or non-interactive? For example `ssh me@example.com 'some-command.sh'` provides a noninteractive  login bash shell.

Comment: It matters a great deal: the ~/.bashrc only gets sourced if you have an interactive shell

Comment: If you specify a command to run, that’s a different ballgame; I thought you were asking about shells you get with plain `ssh me@example.com`. In the `'some-command.sh'` case, the shell is non-interactive, as you’d expect; in the plain SSH case, it’s interactive (`echo $-` shows `i` among other flags).

Comment: In case of `ssh me@example.com 'some-command.sh'`, which startup file(s) is executed, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or something else?

Comment: If you run `ssh me@example.com some-command.sh`, the remote shell won’t execute any startup script, unless you set `BASH_ENV`; see the section describing non-interactive shells.

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't the bash manual explicitly say that that section is only for interactive remote bash shell?

Comment: `ssh me@example.com some-command.sh` gives a noninteractive login shell, which according to the bash manual, should execute `/etc/profile, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile`. Am I correct? The section for non-interactive shells is for noninteractive nonlogin shells, which uses `BASH_ENV`.

Comment: Why don’t you try for yourself? Why would you expect the shell to process your startup scripts when you’re giving it a script to run?